# Javascript GET Request with 301 Redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, http-status-code-301, gorilla

After not being able to figure out what was going wrong, I thought that I'd try my luck on here to see if anyone knows what's going on.

I have an angularJS app with a GoLang/Gorilla mux server backend.
The web app is on http://localhost:8888/ and the server, http://localhost:8080/

Basically I have this simple Javascript GET request:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1'+'/locations/', {borough: "Queens"})
```

Using inspect element, in the response headers I can see the following:

```
Content-Length:68
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 17 Apr 2016 20:12:00 GMT
Location:/api/v1/locations?borough=queens
```

And the following in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/v1/locations/?    borough=queens. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I try the exact same request using Postman and see a 401 with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date →Sun, 17 Apr 2016 19:46:53 GMT
```

Which is what I expect. For some reason, it appears that my request is not even making it to the server, which does not offer a 301 request. The fact that Postman and the app give completely different responses is perplexing.

I had some issues with CORS but thought I resolved that. The fact that Postman gives me a different result with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header makes me think this is something else.

I welcome any help.

**Edit:**

I made the server reply back with the standard Cors parameters. This is what I get now from Postman:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,      Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date →Sun, 17 Apr 2016 20:27:31 GMT
```

Still get the 301 for the JS call...

**Edit2: (tried setting Postman call to exact same as network request)**

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8888
Referer:http://localhost:8888/root/mainapp/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36
```

Still get the same 301 from inspect element and expected 401 with Postman. How can it be that in a Restful HTTP context, we have two identical HTTP calls and yet have completely different behavior out of it?!

Comment: Maybe you should call it in https? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: @mauros Not sure why that would be needed. Anyway, I tried it and get net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: You are making a cross domain request which requires CORS enabled on server. Please do a web search of that error. It comes up numerous times a day here. Postman is not subject to CORS restrictions or `same origin policy`

Comment: @charlietfl I just added an update above. Cors would start with an OPTIONS request. I have handled this with the paameters above. This is a direct GET request that ends up returning a 301 and doesn't even appear to hit the server (I have server logging enabled)

Comment: headers need to be on OPTIONS but you aren't allowing that method

Comment: @charlietfl I have added OPTIONS to be an allowed request. I also added another update above. Still no cigar.

Comment: @charlietfl I just got this to work (see answer below) I still have no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically when I removed the final slash to make it:

from

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1'+'/locations/', {borough: "Queens"})
```

to

```
$.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1'+'/locations', {borough: "Queens"})
```

This worked!!! I have no bloody idea as to why. If I would love to hear from anyone that may know what happened here and why this works. I'll reiterate- because of the last slash, the request didn't even make it to the server.